# estimation of different quotient of a non negative convex function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$: $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^+$ be a differentiable convex function and we recall the difference quotient is defined by
$$
\Delta_hf(x):=\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h.
$$
We have that $\lim_{h\to 0}\Delta_hf(x)=f'(x)$ as well as, since $f(x)$ is convex, that 
$$
\Delta_{h_1} f(x)\geq \Delta_{h_2}f(x)\text{ if }h_1>h_2.
$$
However, could we have some sort of estimation on the value
$$
|\Delta_{h} f(x)-f'(x)|
$$
without reference to the point $x$?

Comment: For any arbitrary convex function $f$ the derivative may not even exist so the question does not  make sense. The estimate you are looking for depends on how smooth your function is.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry I forgot to add this assumption. But somehow I remember that $f$ being convex then it is a.e. differentiable? I might be wrong. Let's just assume $f$ is differentiable

Comment: Yes, it is a.e. differentiable, and always has lateral derivatives.